# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory

Tags: java, maven, twitter4j, apache-storm

When I'm launching on Apache STORM cluster this example source file (with simple storm execution command below) :

```
storm jar storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar storm.starter.PrintSampleStream
```

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter/PrintSampleStream.java

I'm occuring this error on storm environnement (no problem during compilation or maven package process):

```
5503 [Thread-18-twitter] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory
    at twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationContext.<clinit>(ConfigurationContext.java:43) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:41) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<clinit>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:40) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at storm.starter.spout.TwitterSampleSpout.open(TwitterSampleSpout.java:88) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4127$fn__4142.invoke(executor.clj:519) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784.jar:0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__442.invoke(util.clj:434) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784.jar:0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationContext.<clinit>(ConfigurationContext.java:41) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
5503 [Thread-18-twitter] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor - 
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory
    at twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationContext.<clinit>(ConfigurationContext.java:43) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:41) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<clinit>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:40) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at storm.starter.spout.TwitterSampleSpout.open(TwitterSampleSpout.java:88) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4127$fn__4142.invoke(executor.clj:519) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784.jar:0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__442.invoke(util.clj:434) ~[storm-core-0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784.jar:0.9.1.2.1.7.0-784]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationContext.<clinit>(ConfigurationContext.java:41) ~[storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

When I'm running the same code on my local IDE (IntelliJIDEA) there's no crash.

In my pom.xml i already have the Twitter4j dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
<artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
<version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**JDK Version on storm environnement :**

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.1.3.el6_6-x86_64 u85-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
```

When I extract the jar, class "twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory" is not present in conf package , I do not understand why . Can I add it after compilation ?

Does anybody have already occured this execution problem ?

Comment: Is storm-starter-0.10.0-beta1.jar a jar that you created with Maven's assembly plugin that includes all the dependencies?  If the dependencies are not in that jar you've either got to use the assembly plugin's "single" goal or you've got to tell the JVM where it can locate the jars your app needs.  To use assembly plugin add it to the plugins section under build in your pom then run 'mvn assembly:single' to package everything up nice into a single jar.

Comment: n fact, I don't know why, but maven have make a package without some of my dependencies. With mvn assembly:single my package run fine on Apache STORM.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help